# Alternative to ConcurrentDictionary for portable class library

Tags: c#, caching, collections, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm writing a portable class library that targets .NET 4.5, Windows Store apps and Windows Phone 8. I need an efficient in-memory cache mechanism, so I was thinking about using `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`, but it's not available in WP8.

There will be many reads and relatively few writes, so ideally I'd like a collection that supports lock-free reads from multiple threads, and write by a single thread. The non-generic `Hashtable` has that property, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx), but unfortunately it's not available in the PCL...

Is there another collection class available in the PCL that matches this requirement? If not, what would be a good way to achieve thread safety without locking for reads? (locking for writes is OK, since it won't happen too often)

---

EDIT: thanks to JaredPar's guidance, I eventually implemented my cache in a completely lock-free fashion, using `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` from [Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable):

```
class Cache<TKey, TValue>
{
    private IImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> _cache = ImmutableDictionary.Create<TKey, TValue>();

    public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, [NotNull] Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
    {
        valueFactory.CheckArgumentNull("valueFactory");

        TValue newValue = default(TValue);
        bool newValueCreated = false;
        while (true)
        {
            var oldCache = _cache;
            TValue value;
            if (oldCache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                return value;

            // Value not found; create it if necessary
            if (!newValueCreated)
            {
                newValue = valueFactory(key);
                newValueCreated = true;
            }

            // Add the new value to the cache
            var newCache = oldCache.Add(key, newValue);
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _cache, newCache, oldCache) == oldCache)
            {
                // Cache successfully written
                return newValue;
            }

            // Failed to write the new cache because another thread
            // already changed it; try again.
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _cache = _cache.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered writing a type which wrapped an immutable tree, and did a CAS for writes?  That would give you the lock free reads, CAS write and you could just use Eric's immutable AVL tree as the backing structure http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/01/21/immutability-in-c-part-nine-academic-plus-my-avl-tree-implementation.aspx

Comment: @JaredPar, what is "CAS"?

Comment: CAS = compare and swap.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. But isn't it expensive to copy the tree every time I need to add something to it?

Comment: The MSDN says [ConcurentDictionary is in the PCL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx#versionsTitleToggle)...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, it's in the PCL, but only if you select only target platforms that support it. WP8 doesn't support it, so it's not available in a portable class library that targets WP8. PCL only supports the lowest common denominator of the target platforms...

Comment: @JaredPar, it works fine, thanks! It's slower than a dictionary, though, probably due to the O(log n) vs O(1) complexity. If you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it (unless there is a better answer in the meantime...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option to consider is to write a thin facade over an immutable search tree.  There are several immutable search trees available on the web to choose from.  I usually base mine off of Eric Lipperts great post on the subject

- [Immutable Binary Search Tree](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/01/21/immutability-in-c-part-nine-academic-plus-my-avl-tree-implementation.aspx)

Using this as the backing data structure will give you lock free.  Writes to the tree can be done in a lock free fashion with CAS as well.  This will be a bit slower than `ConcurrentDictionary` because lookups are O(Log(N)) instead of approaching O(1).  But it should do the trick for you

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Regarding lock-free writes, I'm not sure how to achieve it... if I don't lock and each writer thread creates a different copy, the second one will overwrite what the first did, won't it?

Comment: Here's how I'm using the tree right now: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/92ad1f8643dfa7a2970a

Comment: @ThomasLevesque take a look at the edits I made.  I tried to explain the logic in the comments https://gist.github.com/jaredpar/20fbdb7ad7fbbb4bd82d

Comment: OK, I see! Thanks for the explanation. I'll have to modify it a bit, because in my case creating the value is quite expensive, so I'd rather not do it several times. Also, I replaced the AVLTree with the ImmutableDictionary class from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable), which has better performance (about 30% faster)

Comment: For the record, here's my final version: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/ecdd3640a0601768386f. Thanks for your help!