# Is there a in memory cache for portable class library?

Tags: c#, caching, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I'm build an app that needs some sort of caching, and since my models and viewmodels live in the portable class library i want some sort of caching there too... but PCL is limited, and I cant seem to find any.

I would like to use System.Runtime.Caching but thats not included in the PCL - is there any other options?

Answer (score 8):

I am looking for such a option myself; I will be rolling my own implementation soon, and will post it. Until then, here are some ideas you may wish to try.

Runtime.Cache if I remember correctly can invalidate cache based on absolute time, sliding time, and monitoring key/files.

First figure out which one you need to implement (I need absolute and sliding though I believe sliding would be costlier)

Have a look at this link.
[alternative-to-concurrentdictionary-for-portable-class-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367839/alternative-to-concurrentdictionary-for-portable-class-library)

My idea is, to extend that class so on each cache item add/remove, we store/remove cache key in a dictionary object with the time to expire (for sliding item we would update this expiry time on read)

Then we have one main timer which checks this dictionary every so often and expires based on time.

If you also want, you can have another dictionary tracking key dependencies, so on key expiry you can expire any other cache depending on this.

Hope this helps in some way.

--- UPDATE

I managed to get around to write my own implementation... here you go..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace RanaInside.CacheProvider
{
internal class CacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    private IDictionary<object, CacheItem> _cache = new Dictionary<object, CacheItem>();
    private IDictionary<object, SliderDetails> _slidingTime = new Dictionary<object, SliderDetails>();

    private const int _monitorWaitDefault = 1000;
    private const int _monitorWaitToUpdateSliding = 500;

    /// <summary>
    /// The sync object to make accessing the dictionary is thread safe.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly object _sync = new object();

    #region Implementation of Interface

    public event EventHandler KeyRemoved;

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a value to the cache with a relative expiry time, e.g 10 minutes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="slidingExpiry">The sliding time when the key value pair should expire and be purged from the cache.</param>
    /// <param name="priority">Normal priority will be purged on low memory warning.</param>
    public void Add<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value, TimeSpan slidingExpiry, CacheItemPriority priority = CacheItemPriority.Normal) where TValue : class
    {
        Add(key, value, slidingExpiry, priority, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a value to the cache with an absolute time, e.g. 01/01/2020.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="absoluteExpiry">The absolute date time when the cache should expire and be purged the value.</param>
    /// <param name="priority">Normal priority will be purged on low memory warning.</param>
    public void Add<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value, DateTime absoluteExpiry, CacheItemPriority priority = CacheItemPriority.Normal) where TValue : class
    {
        if (absoluteExpiry < DateTime.Now)
        {
            return;
        }

        var diff = absoluteExpiry - DateTime.Now;
        Add(key, value, diff, priority, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value from the cache for specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// If the key exists in the cache then the value is returned, if the key does not exist then null is returned.
    /// </returns>
    public TValue Get<TKey, TValue>(TKey key) where TValue : class
    {
        try
        {
            var cacheItem = _cache[key];

            if (cacheItem.RelativeExpiry.HasValue)
            {
                if (Monitor.TryEnter(_sync, _monitorWaitToUpdateSliding))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _slidingTime[key].Viewed();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Monitor.Exit(_sync);
                    }
                }
            }

            return (TValue)cacheItem.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove a value from the cache for specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    public void Remove<TKey>(TKey key)
    {
        if (!Equals(key, null))
        {
            _cache.Remove(key);
            _slidingTime.Remove(key);

            if (KeyRemoved != null)
            {
                KeyRemoved(key, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the contents of the cache.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_sync, _monitorWaitDefault))
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            _cache.Clear();
            _slidingTime.Clear();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_sync);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an enumerator for keys of a specific type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>
    /// Returns an enumerator for keys of a specific type.
    /// </returns>
    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys<TKey>()
    {
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_sync, _monitorWaitDefault))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<TKey>();
        }

        try
        {
            return _cache.Keys.Where(k => k.GetType() == typeof(TKey)).Cast<TKey>().ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_sync);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an enumerator for all the keys
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// Returns an enumerator for all the keys.
    /// </returns>
    public IEnumerable<object> Keys()
    {
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_sync, _monitorWaitDefault))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<object>();
        }

        try
        {
            return _cache.Keys.ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_sync);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the total count of items in cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// -1 if failed
    /// </returns>
    public int TotalItems()
    {
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_sync, _monitorWaitDefault))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        try
        {
            return _cache.Keys.Count;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_sync);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Purges all cache item with normal priorities.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// Number of items removed (-1 if failed)
    /// </returns>
    public int PurgeNormalPriorities()
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_sync, _monitorWaitDefault))
        {
            try
            {
                var keysToRemove = (from cacheItem in _cache where cacheItem.Value.Priority == CacheItemPriority.Normal select cacheItem.Key).ToList();

                return keysToRemove.Count(key => _cache.Remove(key));
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_sync);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    #endregion


    #region Private class helper

    private void Add<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value, TimeSpan timeSpan, CacheItemPriority priority, bool isSliding) where TValue : class
    {
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_sync, _monitorWaitDefault))
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // add to cache
            _cache.Add(key, new CacheItem(value, priority, ((isSliding) ? timeSpan : (TimeSpan?)null)));

            // keep sliding track
            if (isSliding)
            {
                _slidingTime.Add(key, new SliderDetails(timeSpan));
            }

            StartObserving(key, timeSpan);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_sync);
        }
    }

    private void StartObserving<TKey>(TKey key, TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        Observable.Timer(timeSpan)
            .Finally(() =>
            {
                // on finished
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            })
            // on next
            .Subscribe(x => TryPurgeItem(key), 
            exception =>
            {
                // on error: Purge Failed with exception.Message
            });
    }

    private void TryPurgeItem<TKey>(TKey key)
    {
        if (_slidingTime.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            TimeSpan tryAfter;
            if (!_slidingTime[key].CanExpire(out tryAfter))
            {
                // restart observing
                StartObserving(key, tryAfter);
                return;
            }
        }

        Remove(key);
    }

    private class CacheItem
    {
        public CacheItem() { }

        public CacheItem(object value, CacheItemPriority priority, TimeSpan? relativeExpiry = null)
        {
            Value = value;
            Priority = priority;
            RelativeExpiry = relativeExpiry;
        }

        public object Value { get; set; }

        public CacheItemPriority Priority { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan? RelativeExpiry { get; set; }
    }


    private class SliderDetails
    {
        public SliderDetails(TimeSpan relativeExpiry)
        {
            RelativeExpiry = relativeExpiry;
            Viewed();
        }

        private TimeSpan RelativeExpiry { get; set; }

        private DateTime ExpireAt { get; set; }

        public bool CanExpire(out TimeSpan tryAfter)
        {
            tryAfter = (ExpireAt - DateTime.Now);
            return (0 > tryAfter.Ticks);
        }

        public void Viewed()
        {
            ExpireAt = DateTime.Now.Add(RelativeExpiry);
            var z = ExpireAt;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
}
```

For latest updates, please visit my blog at

http://ranahossain.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/cache-provider-for-portable-class.html

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and we created a thread-safe data cache for our needs. It's optimized for mobile devices (similar amounts of read and writes),so we used simple locking instead of ReadWriterLockSlim or other alternatives.

The idea is to add more functionality like events, expirations, tags and locking later. Currently it's only supporting region.

It's part of our LightHouse Framework and can be found in GitHub:

https://github.com/Turneo/LightHouse/blob/master/Code/Core/Core/Code/Caching/DataCache.cs

Answer (score 0):

A very good alternative (but for persistent caches) is [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache).

> Akavache is an asynchronous, persistent (i.e. writes to disk) key-value store created for writing desktop and mobile applications in C#, based on SQLite3. Akavache is great for both storing important data (i.e. user settings) as well as cached local data that expires.

Example snippet from the documentation:

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;   // IMPORTANT - this makes await work!

// Make sure you set the application name before doing any inserts or gets
BlobCache.ApplicationName = "AkavacheExperiment";

var myToaster = new Toaster();
await BlobCache.UserAccount.InsertObject("toaster", myToaster);

//
// ...later, in another part of town...
//

// Using async/await
var toaster = await BlobCache.UserAccount.GetObject<Toaster>("toaster");

// or without async/await
Toaster toaster;

BlobCache.UserAccount.GetObject<Toaster>("toaster")
    .Subscribe(x => toaster = x, ex => Console.WriteLine("No Key!"));
```

Unfortunately if, like me, you are forced to target .NET4 on Desktops, then you are out of luck. But for modern applications I would definitely go with it.

EDIT: I see now that you asked for an in-memory only chache. I don't think Akavache supports that. I'm not deleting this answer, as I think that people googling for PCL Caches might still find it useful.